# Parse JSON file with Java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to parse a JSON file in Java. But the format of the JSON file is complex (at least for me) and hence I have run into a roadblock.

You may read the file-
[Reddit JSON file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EOyjtuZC42Yj80y3Conjw3EXAkC_tXlO)

Within the "reddit" file, the 'key' I am interested in is "body" which is nested deep within the JSON array within the file.

I am using Jackson for parsing and deserialization of the JSON to a Java object and my code is as follows-

```
class Reddit
{
    private String kind;
    private String data;

    public String getData()
    {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setData(String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getKind()
    {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setKind(String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

}


public class Attempting_Read_JSON
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // ObjectMapper can parse JSON into Java Objects, can do vice-versa and more-
        ObjectMapper OM = new ObjectMapper();

        try
        {
            out.println("\nInside try block.\n");
            File json_file = new File("src/main/resources/data/reddit/redditdump.json");
            Reddit[] R = OM.readValue(json_file, Reddit[].class);

            out.println("\nRead from JSON file to 'Reddit class object'\n");

            //out.println("\nObtained JSON- " + R.getData());
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

    out.println("\n\nProgram terminated successfully!\n");
    }
}
```

But on executing the program, it keeps giving me errors.
Any suggestions on how I might get the value associated with the key- 'body'?

Thanks!

Comment: " it keeps giving me errors"   please share errors too

Comment: @shakeel The errors given- com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (File); line: 4, column: 17] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0]->de.dbvis.utils.Reddit["data"])

Answer (score 0):

In your `JSON` file `"data":` is an object and you are trying to assign to `String` in `Reddit` class through `private String data;`.

That's why you are getting this error.

You either need to create a class say `Data` with `members contest_mode, banned_by....` or use JSON Object to parse it.

Also why are you setting `data` here use `kind`

```
    public String getKind()
    {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setKind(String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
```

***EDIT:***
For simplicity I will give you small example:

JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "kind": "Listing",
        "data": {
            "contest_mode": false
        }
    },
    {
        "kind": "Listing",
        "data": {
            "contest_mode": false
        }
    }
]
```

Your code:

```
public class Attempting_Read_JSON {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper OM = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            out.println("\nInside try block.\n");
            File json_file = new File(
                    "src/main/resources/data/reddit/redditdump.json");
            Reddit[] R = OM.readValue(json_file, Reddit[].class);

            out.println("\nRead from JSON file to 'Reddit class object'\n" + R[0].toString());

            // out.println("\nObtained JSON- " + R.getData());
        } catch (Exception E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

        out.println("\n\nProgram terminated successfully!\n");
    }
}

class Reddit {
    private String kind;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Reddit [kind=" + kind + ", data=" + data.toString() + "]";
    }

    private Data data;

    public Data getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getKind() {
        return this.kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }
}

class Data
{
    boolean contest_mode;

    public boolean isContest_mode() {
        return contest_mode;
    }

    public void setContest_mode(boolean contest_mode) {
        this.contest_mode = contest_mode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[contest_mode=" + contest_mode + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any tutorial(s) in mind from where I can refer to how to parse it using JSON object?

Comment: @Arun You can find lots of examples on net. Here is one http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html

Comment: check the EDIT portion